# Hide and Reorder Columns in PagedCollectionView

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid, silverlight-5.0, pagedcollectionview

I'm having a **silverlight 5.0** app in that im having a `PagedCollectionView` which is having an `ObservableCollection` of **Employees**.

I have bound my `PagedCollectionView` to `DataGrid`.

I don't want to show all of my properties of employees in the `datagrid`

and I want to arrange my columns on my own through `PagedCollectionView`

but I don't know how to do it

Please help.

Comment: You Should Add Template For Display Column And Now You Problem Is Solve

Comment: Are you Setisfy With Me ? Or My Ans otherwise i give you full ans

Comment: @Jignesh.Raj Pls do provide full ans.. it ll help much...

Comment: If You Satisfy With My Ans theUpvot Me And Accept My Ans :)

Answer (score 4):

You Should Add Any Control In Template Field And Bind With Pager Properties:

```
<sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource RegularDataGridStyle}" Margin="8"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DemoSeachMast,Path=DataContext.DemmoPager}"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=DemoSeachMast,Path=DataContext.SelectedDemoSearch,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect/>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Effect>

            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Details">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Button x:Name="btnImage" Click="Button_Click" Width="25">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="Transparent">

                                            <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/Window.png" Height="25" Width="25"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>




            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Comment: thanks for the above way.. but is there any possibility with the DisplayIndex property of Datagrid.Columns..??

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it, In both scenario, you need to set **AutoGenerateColumn to false**.

1. If you already know the columns you want to display in the grid during design time, add the columns in the XAML directly.
2. If you do not know the column during design time and if it comes from database with some attribute describing the order and visibility then add autogeneratingcolumn event and in the event, you can make the column visible or do not create the column and even change the order.

****EDIT****

> grid.ItemsSource = Product.GetProducts(200);
>               grid.AutoGeneratingColumn += grid_AutoGeneratingColumn;

> void grid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
>           {
>               string headername = e.Column.Header.ToString();

```
        switch (headername)
        {
            case "Line":
            case "Color":
                e.Cancel = true; //Cancel the columns don't want to generate
                break;
            case "Name":
                e.Column.Header = "Name Modified";
                e.Column.DisplayIndex = 1;
                break;
            case "Price":
                e.Column.Header = "Price header";
                e.Column.DisplayIndex = 0;
                break;
            default:
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

As you can see from the example, Price comes after Name, but not only changed the header I also changed the display order. If you would run, price comes as the first column and Name comes as second column and all other columns are removed from displaying.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=vs.95).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: can u tell me the 2nd way... that too that changing the order

Comment: Added the example in the answer. Please using the last link to understand more if you need.